# Autohide Toolbar for Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any method to have toolbar in android 2.3.3 ? like with features like pop up when click on the top corner . help me

Answer (score 0):

Try widely used ActionBarSherlock http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html.
Download and then compile ABS:Demos, there is lot of sample activities.
Even with how show/hide action bar.